# Eventhandler not removed with new database

Tags: c#, events, umbraco

> [update]I am no longer using an event but I would really like to find out why this might have happened.

I have an eventhandler that duplicates content nodes in the umbraco back-office for a multilang site.

This was working perfectly until I changed my umbraco db to that of a colleague (which shouldn't make any difference to the code).

Stepping through my code I see that the handler isn't removed (or rather it seems to be removed but fires anyway) and the nodes are being replicated over and over.

```
foreach (var id in _listOfParentIds.Where(id => id != parentNode.Id))
{
      lock (Locker)
      {
            Document.New -= SaveLangDupelicates;    //  remove event to prevent it from firing after copying
            dupeDoc.Copy(id, User.GetCurrent(), true);  //  copy the document to the relevant parent node                                   
            Document.New += SaveLangDupelicates;    //  reinstate the event
      }
}
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: check if `Document` is another object after `dupeDoc.Copy` by looking at the `HashTag`value

Comment: @Alechandro the doc has to be a new object, and it was working fine before, I just have no idea why the event fires again.

Comment: I suggest hooking up your previous db and stepping through to ensure that it wasn't happening before. If the db's are essentially the same, then I would just check the code for sanity's sake.